# Некорректное отображение превью XAML кода в Visual Studion 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Случайно внесла какие-то изменения в настройках Visual Studio 2015 - теперь некорректно отображается превью XAML кода. В других окнах только вот такое отображение границ контролов. Удаление программы не помогло.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался, знает как исправить? Пожалуйста, помогите исправить!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На чистом проекте воспроизводится или нет?

Comment: Новый проект создается, окно отображается. А в моем проекте все сломано(

Comment: А если на файле `XAML` кликнуть правой и выбрать пункт `Design in Blend`? Или сразу открыть проект в Blend?

Comment: можно XAML код в студию и .cs файл к нему

Comment: А Rebuild не помогает?

Comment: нет(( нифига не помогает

Comment: Попробуйте удалить все папки `obj`, `bin` и скрытые `.vs` из папки с солюшеном. После запустите солюшн и сбилдите его.

Comment: помогло!!! спасибо огромнейшее))))

Comment: @Dasha: Раз ответ помог, поставьте ему зелёную галку (слева).

Answer (score 1):

Удалите все папки `obj`, `bin` и скрытые `.vs` из папки с солюшеном. После запустите солюшн и сбилдите его.